# index page not displaying in springboot thymleaf layout dialect

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I posted a question few days ago about jquery code not working in a thymeleaf template as expected. I am able to do it without using jquery but it has generated another problem and I need help. I cant display index.html and below is code sample

```
stylecss file
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;;
}

.wrapper .header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  background: #23242b;
  color: #fff;
}
.wrapper .u-name{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 17px;
}
.wrapper .u-name span{
  color: #127b8e;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.wrapper .header i{
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
.wrapper .header i:hover{
  color: #127b83;
}
/* .wrapper .user-p{
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.wrapper .user-p img{
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
} */
.wrapper .user-p h4{
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.wrapper .side-bar{
  width: 300px;
  background: #262931;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: 500ms width;
}
.wrapper .sidebarmenu{
  display: flex;
  position:absolute;
}

.wrapper .section-1{
  width: 100%;
  background: url("./img/bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper .side-bar ul{
  margin-top: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
.wrapper .side-bar ul li{

  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  transition: 500ms background;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.wrapper .side-bar ul li:hover{
  background: #127b8e;
}
 .wrapper .side-bar ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

part of the css code

```
.wrapper .side-bar ul li a i{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.wrapper #navbtn{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 500ms color;
}
.wrapper #checkbox{
  display: none;
}
/*hides and show the sidebar */
.wrapper #checkbox:checked ~ .sidebarmenu .side-bar{
  width: 60px;
}
.wrapper #checkbox:checked ~ .sidebarmenu .side-bar .user-p{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.wrapper #checkbox:checked ~ .sidebarmenu .side-bar a span{
display: none;
}
.wrapper #checkbox:checked ~ .sidebarmenu .side-bar ul li label{
display: none;
}
.wrapper #A{
  display: none;
}
.wrapper #A:checked ~ ul{
  display: block;
}
.wrapper .side-bar ul li i{
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #eee;
}
.wrapper .side-bar ul li label{
  color: #eee;
}
.wrapper .side-bar ul li label i{
  float: right;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.wrapper .side-bar ul li ul li{
  line-height: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 50px;

}
.wrapper .side-bar ul li ul li:hover{
  padding-left: 52px;
}
.wrapper .side-bar ul li ul{
   display: none;

}
```

header html file contains the whole menu navigation bar

```
<header>
<div class="wrapper">

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <header class="header">
      <h2 class="u-name">ECC <span>Soft</span>
        <label for="checkbox">
          <i id="navbtn" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
      </h2>
      <i  class="fas fa-user" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
    </header>
    <div class="sidebarmenu">
      <nav class="side-bar">
        <!-- <div class="user-p">
          <img src="img/sprofile.jpg" alt="">
          <h4>Peter</h4>
        </div> -->
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <span>Dashboard</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="A">
                <i class="far fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <label for="A">
                  <span>Message</span>
                  <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
                </label>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">UI/UX Designer</a> </li>
                  <li><a href="#">UI Designer</a> </li>
                  <li><a href="#">UX Designer</a> </li>
                </ul>

          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="far fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <span>Comments</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <span>About</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <span>Settings</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <span>Logout</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
</div>
```

main layout file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
<!-- webjars and static resources referencing -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/style.css"
    th:href="@{css/style.css}" />
 <link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.css}">
 <link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
 <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
```

body of main layout file

```
<body>
    <div th:replace="fragments/header::header"></div>

    <div layout:fragment="content">

    </div>

    <div th:replace="fragments/footer::footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

index html file. This is the file am battling with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="~{fragments/main_layout}">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div layout:fragment="content" class="container">
       <div class="card">           
            <p>Thank you for using ecc soft</p>          
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Since Thymeleaf and JavaScript are unrelated you should ignore the Thymeleaf templates and just look at the generated HTML in the browser and use the browsers development tools to debug the JavaScript.

Comment: The code actually works without thymeleaf in a browser but it stop working when run it in ide with thymeleaf.

Comment: I have solve this problem long time ago and I forget to comment it here. The problem was from where I place the script files. I found out that the layout fragment only display the files put in the layout:fragment="content" and layout:decorate="~{fragments/main_layout}" does not include the files in the header.  I created a head fragment where I placed only the script files and invoke in it in all the pages.